# Extract strings and numbers from text

Tags: regex

I have strings like `10E4558AA0_String1_String2_String3_0_100_12mo`.  I want to pull out `string1` and `string2` and also `0` and `100`.
The `0_100` could also be `0_10`, `11_25`, `26_75` or `76_100` and I'd want to pull out `0 10`, `11 25`, `26 75`, `76 100`, respectively. I think a regex would work but I am struggling with the coding part.

Comment: yes you are correct..a regex will work, but what have you tried?

Comment: Everything you mention you want to pull out is unrelated. It's equivalent to `string[12]|0|100`

Comment: Please elaborate on your regex flavor/programming language used.

Comment: What environment/language are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

## via Split

Since your string is delimited by `_` either a split command, but this varies from language to language.

Javascript would look something like `str.split("_")`, and more language examples of tokenizing a string could be found at [rosettacode.org](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Tokenize_a_string)

---

## via Regex Matching

To do this strictly via regular expression matching you can add in some string validation like in the following regex.

```
^([0-9a-f]+)_(string[^_]+)_(string[^_]+)_(string[^_]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([^_]+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/yT4bR4/1

**Sample text**

```
10E4558AA0_String1_String2_String3_0_100_12mo
```

**Sample Matches**

```
[0][0] = 10E4558AA0_String1_String2_String3_0_100_12mo
[0][1] = 10E4558AA0
[0][2] = String1
[0][3] = String2
[0][4] = String3
[0][5] = 0
[0][6] = 100
[0][7] = 12mo
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9a-f]+                any character of: '0' to '9', 'a' to 'f'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    string                   'string'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_]+                    any character except: '_' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    string                   'string'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_]+                    any character except: '_' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    string                   'string'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_]+                    any character except: '_' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \5:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \5
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \6:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \6
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \7:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_]+                    any character except: '_' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \7
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```